# OpenSceneGraph: Texture coordinates for the triangles set

Tags: textures, coordinates, openscenegraph

I need help with calculating texture coordinates for the set of triangles. Is there a function that calculates them according to the vertex coordinates without shaders? Or how one can calculate them manually using vertex normals? 
I have a big amount of small triangles, calculated from a point cloud and have no possibility to influence them. My simplified test program looks like this:

```
    //read texture
    text = new_message->text;
    osg::ref_ptr<osg::Texture2D> texture = new osg::Texture2D;
    texture->setDataVariance(osg::Object::DYNAMIC);
    osg::ref_ptr<osg::Image> image = osgDB::readImageFile( "Images/" +text );

    if (!image)
    {
    std::cout << "Couldn't load texture." << std::endl;
    }
    texture->setImage( image.get() );
    ...
    //create and fill an array of vertices
    osg::ref_ptr<osg::Vec3Array> vertices = new osg::Vec3Array;
    vertices->push_back( osg::Vec3(...) );
    ...
    osg::ref_ptr<osg::Geometry> quad = new osg::Geometry;
    quad->setVertexArray( vertices.get() );
    quad->addPrimitiveSet( new osg::DrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 12) );
    //calculate normals
    osgUtil::SmoothingVisitor::smooth( *quad );
    geode = new osg::Geode;
    geode->addDrawable( quad.get() );
    //calculate texture coordinates
    osg::StateSet *state = geode->getOrCreateStateSet();
    state->setTextureAttributeAndModes(1, texture.get(), osg::StateAttribute::ON);
    state->setTextureMode(1, GL_TEXTURE_GEN_S, osg::StateAttribute::ON);
    state->setTextureMode(1, GL_TEXTURE_GEN_T, osg::StateAttribute::ON);
    state->setTextureMode(1, GL_TEXTURE_GEN_R, osg::StateAttribute::ON);
    state->setTextureMode(1, GL_TEXTURE_GEN_Q, osg::StateAttribute::ON);
    geode->setStateSet(state);
```

The calculated normals work perfectly, texture coordinates are not working at all - I get black triangles. There is not much information on how to use  GL_TEXTURE_GEN_S, so any help would be really appreciated. 
UPD: I calculated texture coordinates manually using following formulas 
http://paulyg.f2s.com/uv.htm

Answer (score 0):

[GL_TEXTURE_GEN_* generates texture coordinates according to some parametric function (e.g. mapping world or model coordinates, reflection vectors etc.)](https://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/version1.1/glspec1.1/node27.html)

You don't state what you're actually trying to achieve, but to obtain any texture coordinates, the `GL_TEXTURE_GEN_*` could work. Otherwise, you could iterate over your point cloud's vertices and normals and generate the texture coordinates on the CPU-side, within the `osg::Geometry`. This would work in the same manner as you assigned the vertices to the geometry, but with a different function to calculate the actual coordinates, depending on your needs.